# Windows 10 Best Place for Sharing Data between Multiple User Accounts

Tags: windows, virtualstore

I'm converting a suite of legacy 32 bit C++ apps to run under Windows 10. These apps can run under different user accounts on the same PC and need to share the data between themselves and all the users. Some of the apps are Windows services, some are regular UI apps. There's a lot of communication between the apps and sometimes this is accomplished using shared data files. All the different user accounts need to access the shared data...

I have tried storing the shared data in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\AppName\data

and have set the security level on that folder to Full Control for All users.

Most of the time, this works perfectly well. But occasionally, at seemingly random intervals, one of the shared data files ends up in:

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\AppName\data

I have tried to replicate this, and it never happens when I'm looking...

If I run a simple UI app that just writes to this folder, everything is fine. The App does not need to run with elevated privileges to write to the folder.

I suspect it's when one of the Apps is trying to write to a file that is locked by another, which the code handles by using exceptions, but Windows tries to help out by writing to the VirtualStore instead. But I could be wrong...

So, to cut to the question:

Where is the 'best place' to store shared data between several apps AND user accounts, that won't end up in the VirtualStore?

Andy

Comment: A natural choice is `\Users\Public` or `\ProgramData` for read-only stuff. If the app expects it to be under `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, put a symlink there.

Comment: What you see may be caused by some 'antivirus', 'endpoint security', 'privilege management' or other such stuff. If you have these, try to disable them temporarily.

Comment: Thankd ddbug. Unfortunately, this is shared read/write data between different Windows user accounts. It's not an ideal setup, but this is a legacy system that has been this way for years and it's so ingrained in the system that it's hard to take out quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any application with a `requestedExecutionLevel` node in its [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests) is marked as Vista compatible and the redirection to the Virtual Store is disabled.

Comment: Thanks Anders

As the PC's with our system on it are used for nothing else (we even replace the Windows shell with our own to prevent other uses) I've also considered setting Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableVirtualization to zero, to turn it off system wide...